# How to convert the number of matrix to fraction not decimal in python?

Tags: python

I have one matrix in python:

```
aa = np.array([[1, -2], [1, 1]])
```

Then, I want to compute the inverse of this matrix aa:

```
bb = inv(aa)
Finally, I got the result:
print("bb: ", bb)
array([[ 0.33333333,  0.66666667], [-0.33333333,  0.33333333]]))
```

But I want to print the results in fraction format, not decimal/float:

```
array([[ 1/3,  2/3], [-1/3,  1/3]]))
```

Here is my original codes:

```py
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv
from fractions import Fraction

aa = np.array([[1, -2], [1, 1]])
bb = inv(aa)
print("bb: ", bb)
```

How can I get this print result by python?

```
array([[ 1/3,  2/3], [-1/3,  1/3]]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org/):

```
from sympy import Matrix

aa = Matrix([[1, -2], [1, 1]])
bb = aa.inv()
print(bb)  # Matrix([[1/3, 2/3], [-1/3, 1/3]])
```

Comment: this helped me but if you already have fraction as elements in your matrix, then printing that matrix will convert the fraction to decimals :/ i haven't found a solution yet

Comment: @brian how did you create this matrix? in python 3 `1/3` is a `float`. are you sure the elements in your matrix are instances of [`Fraction`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction) (or something like it)?

Comment: oooh i see, for example i had this matrix
bc = mat([[0,4/5,3/5],[1,0,0],[0,3/5,-4/5]])

Comment: then i used the Rational module and it ended up working
bc = mat([[0,Rational(4,5),Rational(3,5)],[1,0,0],[0,Rational(3,5),Rational(-4,5)]])

Comment: @brian ah, yes, sympy uses [`Rational`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#sympy.core.numbers.Rational)s, you are right! hope that helped!